# normal-distributions on mixed-effect models

Tags: normal-distribution, mixed-model, assumptions

Mixed effect models do not assume gaussianity of the data, they assume normal and constant-variance residuals. However, I run into an example that is confusing me. I am trying to model the changes of muscle activations (integral of electromyographic signal, variable `emg`) over days. These data are highly skewed, and I thought that would not be a problem for LMM. However, I get much better fitting and predictions if I log-transform the data. Does anybody have a clue of why this may be the case?

If I do not log-transform, the residuals won't have constant variance, and I need to account for that in my model (using weights=varPower() in the lme call). This leads to better fit and predictions than without modeling the variance, but the results of the fit is still much worse than when log-transform the data.

Comment: The classic linear mixed model (LMM) analysis assumes that the residuals (conditional on the random effects), as well as the random effects themselves, are Guassian. This implies that the data have some multivariate normal distribution. It could be that the data you are dealing with is skewed, or doesn't have constant variance, in which case the LMM assumptions will not not satisfied. Taking the log transform could help alleviate this issue. Have you looked at QQ plots of the residuals/BLUPS, and a plot of the predicted vs. actual responses?

Comment: Thanks! The data are indeed skewed, but I thought that it was OK as the data are not assumed to be gaussian. The residuals do not have constant variance. To deal with this, I have used an extended LMM where I provide a model for the variance. Yet, fit and predictions are better when I log-transform the data.

Comment: Why do the assumptions of the LMM imply that the data have some multivariate normal distribution? Do you have references for this?